# Julia: calling Array() with an array of dimensions

Tags: julia

Suppose I want to create a multidimensional array whose dimensions / size per dimension are specified in an array. I want to do something like this:

```
dims = [2,5,6] # random example, the idea is I don't know dims ahead of time
arr = Array(Float64, dims)
```

That is not allowed. In the above case one should use:

```
arr = Array(Float64, dims[1], dims[2], dims[3] )
```

I don't know the length of dims ahead of time, so the above solution doesn't work for me.
Is there a clean workaround outside of using some nasty sprintfs and eval?

Thanks!

Comment: You usually don't use sprintf with eval in julia. There are much better options for metaprogramming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A really useful operator to remember in Julia is the “splat”, `...`. In this case you simply want:

```
arr = Array(Float64, dims...)
```